# Can I put an Image(s) on a Canvas and have them be moved around by the mouse?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I want to dynamically create and put some Image (mx.controls.Image) objects on a Canvas and I want them then to be able to be repositioned by the user via the mouse. Can this be done? Note, I am not looking for drag and drop. I just want to change the X and Y coordinates of Images with the mouse.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? I don't see the difference between what you want and drag&drop.

Answer (score 0):

Just listen for mouse events and change the position of the object appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the same tools from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030857/approaches-libraries-for-resize-dragging) may help you get started:

- [flex-object-handles](http://code.google.com/p/flex-object-handles/)
- [Transform Manager](http://www.greensock.com/transformmanageras3/)